# Изменился серийный номер Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

После крупного обновления Windows 10 Home сменился серийный номер ОС. Так как занимаюсь лицензированием ПО в нашей конторе, то возникает логичный вопрос:

По какому принципу изменяется серийный номер ОС Windows?

*Был у меня номер*: 00432-20001-25992-**AB036**

*Стал*: 00432-20001-25992-**AB331**

Если изменяться будут только выделенные символы, то проблем нету, но мне нужны 100% гарантии. Не использовать серийник не могу, этот вопрос я уже обдумывал.

*Серийные номера выдуманы.*

Comment: Не думаю что подобный вопрос найдет тут ответ. Попробуйте постучаться в сапорт самого майкрософта - ведь наличие лицензионного ПО предполагает качественную поддержку.

Comment: Тем более что в отношении Windows 100%-ую гарантию вам может дать **только поддержка Microsoft**.

Comment: @alexoander, честно, лень там регистрироваться. Но если дело дойдёт, то опишу тут всё что смогу узнать.

Comment: Я думаю вам будут благодарны Win10 юзеры, которые столкнутся с подобным. Ну а лень она и в Африке лень =)

Comment: На сколько я знаю - проверяющие органы плевать хотели на UUID винды. Им нужна бумажка с печатью и голограммой. Ну или договор от дистрибутора. Ну или чек.

Comment: @alexoander, постарался расписать всё что выяснил от мелкомягких

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Главное: "Серийный номер" == "Код продукта"

При общении с техподом microsoft выяснили, что я не верно гуглил. То что я вытаскивал из класса `Win32_OperatingSystem.SerialNumber` - это не **серийный номер**, а **код продукта**!

#### Код продукта в Windows 10

Техподдержка MS не смогла дать развёрнутый ответ, тем более про другие версии ОС, всё что сказали - это касается "десятки".

В реале код продукта имеет такой формат: **00326-10006-ХХХХХ-AA331**.

Первое важное замечание техподдержки:

> Код продукта - это уникальный идентификатор установленного образа системы. Именно последние три цифры после значения AA будут отличатся.

Второе - по поводу формата первых трёх блоков:

> Первые цифры относятся к редакции (прим. первый блок в коде продукта)
>
> 00326 - Домашняя
>
> 00327 - Домашняя для одного языка
>
> 00330 - Профессиональная
>
> Вот эти цифры не будут изменены.
> Остальные идентификаторы, сообщают о принадлежности лицензии по типу OEM или Retail (прим. второй блок в коде продукта).

В принципе это вся информация которой обладает техподдержка, больше я не смог ничего от них добиться. Про третий блок, как я сам понял - это какой-то номер для уникальности.

#### Код продукта других ОС Windows

Что касается других версий ОС техподдержка ничего сказать вразумительного не смогла:

> Здесь не подскажу. Там он может не изменяться после выхода обновления. Код продукта в данных операционных системах изменяется лишь после ввода ключа.

К моему сожалению по ключевым словам "Код продукта" и "Product ID" ничего от самих MS я не нашёл ничего вразумительного. Нашёл небольшую статью в которой попытались проанализировать формат кода продукта, ознакомиться можно [тут](http://defacto-com.ru/articles/productid.pdf) (не является официальным документом).